# text/html blob that is source of iframe that has html and JS code in it, creates mimetype error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mime-types

I am working on creating an iframe that will have both html and JS code in it.  The code going into the blob will be something like:

'''

```
    <script src="{%  static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" > </script> 
    <script src="https://<domain>/controller/api_browser_retrieve_script/"></script>

    <html>
    <body>
           stuff in the html...
```

'''

The second script src that is pointed to 'https://../api_browser_retrieve_script/' then pulls in a file of JS code from an application - and I want this script to then be available in the iframe for use in the html, as inline JS is getting dumped by my CSP policies.

This template of code from above is then put into a variable called iframecode and made into a blob called blobContent:

```
const blobContent = new Blob([iframecode], {type: "text/html"});
var iFrameM = document.createElement("iframe");
iFrameM.src = URL.createObjectURL(blobContent);
window.frames[0].document.body.appendChild(iFrameM);
```

However, when iFrameM is appended to the main page, the blob will start to load in the iframe, and then the browser will see the script tags and then fail to load the rest due to a Mimetype error. I can set the mimetype to 'application/javascript', but then the html no longer works.  Is there a way to get the blob to load into the iframe and have the iframe still load the JS code and run properly?

Comment: where is iframeCode defined?

Comment: Since the protocol are differ on your current page(http or https) and on iframe(blob), the browsers will think you are trying to make a Cross Site Scripting (XSS), and will deny the operation

Comment: iframeCode is set to equal the first code block.  Everything in that section is dumped into that variable.  That line of code was omitted for brevity.

Comment: I do not believe that the browser is seeing an XSS issue. If I change the mimetype to application/javascript, the JS code will load, but then the html is ignored.

Comment: To be clear here, are you trying to create an iframe or put an iframe into an existing one? Your last line of code implies the latter but the writeup implies for former.

Comment: I am creating an iframe and then adding the blob code into that iframe.  There is only one iframe that we are working with.